# Snowflake: how to turn a time-series rows into contiguous columns?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that stores the steps by that an item is transferred (purposely made in SQL for ease of reproduction):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ITEM_PROCESS (PK_ID, ID, DATE, STATUS, NAME)
AS
SELECT * FROM VALUES
(1, 1, '2023-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, 'Arrive in Warehouse', 'PS5'),
(2, 1, '2023-02-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, 'Packaging', 'PS5'),
(3, 1, '2023-03-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, 'Shipping', 'PS5'),
(4, 1, '2023-04-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, 'Received', 'PS5'),
(5, 2, '2023-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, 'Arrive in Warehouse', 'Fan'),
(6, 2, '2023-01-02 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, 'Checking failures', 'Fan'),
(7, 2, '2023-01-03 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, 'Shipping', 'Fan'),
(8, 2, '2023-01-04 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, 'Received', 'Fan')
```

I want to do something like [`PIVOT`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot) for the column `STATUS` that "breaks" it into multiple columns and insert the corresponding `DATE` as the value. Expected output:

| ID | Arrive in Warehouse | Checking failures | Packaging | Shipping | Received | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |  | 2023-02-01 | 2023-03-01 | 2023-04-01 | PS5 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-02 |  | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-04 | Fan |

Some assumptions and requirements that I have to follow:

- The name order of the flow are known beforehand in a separate table, it looks like `(1, 'Arrive in Warehouse'), (2, 'Checking failures'), (3, 'Packaging'),...`
- The "pivot" process should not change the order of the columns. As you see in the example,   `Name` is the last column in the table, and it should also be the last column in the "pivoted" table. In my actual table, there are 3 columns before the `DATE` column and a lot of them after the `STATUS` column.
- Each combination of `ID-DATE-STATUS` appears only once in the table, so no need to de-duplicate it.
- There is a Primary Key for each row. Not sure if it is helpful.

I have been trying to do it for days but I don't know how to do it. I am fine with either SQL or Stored Procedure, but I prefer Python SP if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway that the query can be further generalized?

You can use an anonymous block to generate the SQL and run it like this:

```
execute immediate $$
declare c cursor for select STATUS, min("DATE") MIN_DATE from ITEM_PROCESS group by STATUS order by MIN_DATE;
        sql string;
        rs resultset;
begin
    sql := 'select ID, NAME';
    for record in c do
        sql := sql || '\n,max(iff(STATUS = ''' || record.STATUS || ''', "DATE", NULL)) "' || record.STATUS || '"';
    end for;
    sql := sql || '\nfrom ITEM_PROCESS group by ID, NAME';
    rs := (execute immediate :sql);
    return table(rs);
end;
$$;
```

| ID | NAME | Arrive in Warehouse | Checking failures | Shipping | Received | Packaging |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PS5 | 2023-01-01 | null | 2023-03-01 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-02-01 |
| 2 | Fan | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-04 | null |

The anonymous block constructs and immediately executes a SQL statement like this:

```
select ID, NAME
,max(iff(STATUS = 'Arrive in Warehouse', "DATE", NULL)) "Arrive in Warehouse"
,max(iff(STATUS = 'Checking failures', "DATE", NULL)) "Checking failures"
,max(iff(STATUS = 'Shipping', "DATE", NULL)) "Shipping"
,max(iff(STATUS = 'Received', "DATE", NULL)) "Received"
,max(iff(STATUS = 'Packaging', "DATE", NULL)) "Packaging"
from ITEM_PROCESS group by ID, NAME
```

It will order the STATUS columns based on their first appearance in the table by date. If you want to order some other way, you can change the SQL for the line starting with `declare c cursor for`. Whatever order you specify in that SQL will drive the ordinal position order of the columns in the result.

Edit: I re-read your question and it has this:

> The name order of the flow are known beforehand in a separate table, it looks like (1, 'Arrive in Warehouse'), (2, 'Checking failures'), (3, 'Packaging'),...

In this case, you can just join to that table to get the order you want. You can run the `c cursor` SQL statement by itself to get the order the way you want it, and the cursor will read the `STATUS` in the order they appear in that result.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this query

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Arrive in Warehouse' THEN DATE END) AS "Arrive in Warehouse",
  MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Checking failures' THEN DATE END) AS "Checking failures",
  MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Packaging' THEN DATE END) AS "Packaging",
  MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Shipping' THEN DATE END) AS "Shipping",
  MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Received' THEN DATE END) AS "Received",
  MAX(NAME) AS NAME
FROM ITEM_PROCESS 
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/QnLeQI3r)
(the demo is in PostgreSQL, but since this query use T-SQL syntax, so it should work on your DB).

Comment: Is there anyway that the query can be further generalized? The `STATUS` column contains a lot of values, and the number of columns behind `NAME` is also about 100...

Comment: To do pivot in SQL, it's needed to have pre-defined pivot values. If there are list of dynamic values that need to pivot, it's better to do it in Stored Procedures.